# Unknown Parameter to Push Values to Dynamic Struct Array

Tags: solidity, web3js, arrays, struct

I am trying to use Web3.js to push values from my frontend to a dynamic struct array in my backend.

However, I am receiving an error that I need to provide a parameter to my frontend: "Unhandled Rejection (Error): Invalid number of parameters for "challenges". Got 0 expected 1!"

I have no idea what this parameter is. Would anyone happen to know what this parameter could be? My code is provided below. Help would be insanely appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Given the following data-structure:

```
struct Type {
    string  field1;
    address field2;
    uint256 field3;
}
```

And the following state-variable:

```
Type[] public array;
```

The compiler generates the following getter-function:

```
function array(uint256 index) public view returns (string, address, uint256) {
    return (array[index].field1, array[index].field2, array[index].field3);
}
```

So you should call `challenges(index)` with some integer value of `index`.